# How to deal with underflow in R?

Tags: r, precision, numeric, exponential, underflow

I want to compute this number :
0.34911191 ^ 1157
I am using R programming language and it returns me **0** (this is an underflow problem). How I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, the packages Rmpfr and Ryacas don't work

Comment: What does *"don't work"* mean? Can you describe the expected result?

Comment: It's unlikely that either of those packages has some issue that makes them fundamentally not work, and much more likely that something about _your implementation_ of them didn't work. Without any of your code, we don't know what that might be. That post also has 4 answers on it, not just the one that mentioned those 2 packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?
The CRAN package [`Brobdingnag`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=Brobdingnag) has two vignettes explaining its use.

```
library(Brobdingnag)

x <- 1157 * log(0.34911191)
y <- as.brob(x)
exp(y)
#[1] +exp(-1217.6)
exp(y) < .Machine$double.neg.eps
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test the result using the [Numerical Characteristics of the Machine](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zMachine.html) (`.Machine {base}`), as shown below:

```
> 0.34911191 ^ 10 < .Machine$double.neg.eps
[1] FALSE
> 0.34911191 ^ 1157 < .Machine$double.neg.eps
[1] TRUE
```

`double.neg.eps` is a small positive floating-point number x such that 1 - x != 1.